# Is there anyway I can import my own feature_importances into a model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, artificial-intelligence, xgboost

I was wondering whether I am able to import feature_importances from let's say model1 to model2, such that I can then train model2 starting from these feature_importances, and let model2 influence these feature_importances to create a new set of "Mutated" feature_importances.

Thanks in advance

I tried just doing something like this
`model2.feature_importances_ = model1.feature_importances_`
but it just threw an error at me saying `AttributeError: can't set attribute 'feature_importances_'`. Which is expectable.

Comment: Please add your code, and more info around which libraries (versions of libraries) and models are you using. Right now your question doesn't give any information that will allow others to answer your query with a specific answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are confusing the `feature_importances_` property with `feature_weights` parameter in xgboost.

---

### Feature importances are a post-statistic not a model parameter

Feature importance is a post-statistic that is calculated in different ways such as [mean decrease in impurity](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_forest_importances.html#feature-importance-based-on-mean-decrease-in-impurity), [feature permutation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_forest_importances.html#feature-importance-based-on-feature-permutation), etc. The goal of these statistics is to give a relative sense of which features were a better predictor for the prediction task at hand.

An example of a popular `feature_importance_` statistic is called `Gini importance`.

> The importance of a feature is computed as the (normalized) total reduction of the criterion brought by that feature. It is also known as the Gini importance. Details [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.feature_importances_).

`feature_importances_` is a property which is calculated and saved as part of the model class instance after the `model.fit()` method is called. You can NOT overwrite this attribute and even if you could, it would not allow you to make any changes to the model training like you are expecting.

---

### Feature weights can help "prioritize" a given feature during training

What you need is `feature_weights` parameter, which is a part of the `xgboost.XGBRegressor.fit` and the `xgboost.XGBClassifier.fit`.

> `feature_weights` (Optional[Any]) – Weight for each feature, defines the probability of each feature being selected when colsample is being used. All values must be greater than 0, otherwise, a ValueError is thrown.

Read more details on `feature_weights` [here](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#xgboost.XGBRegressor.fit). You have to make sure you use any of the `colsample_*` parameters in the model instantiation and then pass your `feature_weights` for each feature as an array to the `.fit()` methods. By default, each of the `feature_weights` are set to 1.

Here is an example of the usage of these paramters.

```
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

#Load data
data = load_iris()
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data['data'], 
                                                    data['target'], 
                                                    test_size=.2)

#Train model
xgb = XGBClassifier(n_estimators=5, 
                    objective='binary:logistic', 
                    colsample_bytree = 0.7)                 #<--------

feature_weights = np.array([0.5, 0.3, 0.8, 0.1])            #<--------
xgb.fit(X_train, y_train, feature_weights=feature_weights)  #<--------


preds = xgb.predict(X_test)
xgb.feature_importances_
```

```
array([0.09477486, 0.03003547, 0.77826285, 0.09692684], dtype=float32)
```

---

### Can you use the `feature_importances_` from a previous model as `feature_weights`?

As long as your understand ...

1. how the colsample_* parameters use these `feature_weights` for sampling/prioritizing specific columns,
2. that `feature_importances_` are not probabilities, and `feature_weights` are probabilities (don't need to sum up to 1 but have to be > 0),

... I don't see why not.

You can pass `feature_importances_` from say a previously run random forest model as feature priority for the xgboost model using the `colsample_*` and `feature_weights` parameters. After the model training, you can pull your new "mutated" `feature_importances_`. Be careful of comparing these `feature_importances_` across models thought.

Comment: Oh, I see. This makes much more sense. Thank you so much for the detailed explanation.