# How to assign feature weights in XGBClassifier?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, xgboost

I am trying to assign a higher weight to one feature above others. Here is my code.

```
## Assign weight to High Net Worth feature
cols = list(train_X.columns.values)

# 0 - 1163 --Other Columns
# 1164 --High Net Worth

#Create an array of feature weights
other_col_wt = [1]*1164
high_net_worth_wt = [5]
feature_wt = other_col_wt + high_net_worth_wt
feature_weights = np.array(feature_wt)

# Initialize the XGBClassifier
xgboost = XGBClassifier(subsample = 0.8, # subsample = 0.8 ideal for big datasets
                        silent=False,  # whether print messages during construction
                        colsample_bytree = 0.4, # subsample ratio of columns when constructing each tree
                        gamma=10, # minimum loss reduction required to make a further partition on a leaf node of the tree, regularisation parameter
                        objective='binary:logistic',
                        eval_metric = ["auc"],
                        feature_weights = feature_weights
                      )
# Hypertuning parameters
lr = [0.1,1] # learning_rate = shrinkage for updating the rules
ne = [100] # n_estimators = number of boosting rounds
md = [3,4,5] # max_depth = maximum tree depth for base learners

# Grid Search
clf = GridSearchCV(xgboost,{
    'learning_rate':lr,
    'n_estimators':ne,
    'max_depth':md
},cv = 5,return_train_score = False)

# Fitting the model with the custom weights
clf.fit(train_X,train_y, feature_weights = feature_weights)
clf.cv_results_
```

I went through the documentation [here](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#xgboost.XGBClassifier.fit) and this Akshay Sehgal's stackoverflow response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75025394/is-there-anyway-i-can-import-my-own-feature-importances-into-a-model/75025752#75025752) for a similar question. But when I use the above code, I get below error?

[image]

Could anyone please help me where I am doing it wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to remove `feature_weights` from the init of `XGBClassifier`. At least, this works when I try your example.